# Splitting a row columns into multiple rows in R

Tags: split, row

I have a data frame with multiple columns. However, I need to move certain columns into a separate row while keeping identical columns data as is. Below are my source and expected data frames.

## Source Dataframe

```
ID1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
Name1 <- c("Adam", "Adam", "Bryan", "Bryan", "Craig", "Craig", "David", "David")
Name2_1 <- c("Elan", "Elan", "Fowler","Fowler", "Greg", "Greg", "Harry", "Harry")
Name2_2 <- c("Ivan", "Ivan", "Jake", "Jake", "Kern", "Kern", "Lewis", "Lewis")
Test1 <- c("A1", "EI1", "B1", "FJ1", "C1", "GK1", "D1", "HL1")

dft1 <- data.frame(ID1, Name1, Name2_1, Name2_2, Test1)
```

## Target Dataframe

```
ID2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
Name21 <- c("Adam", NA, "Bryan", NA, "Craig", NA, "David", NA)
Name21_1 = c(NA, "Elan", NA,"Fowler", NA, "Greg", NA, "Harry")
Name21_2 = c(NA, "Ivan", NA, "Jake", NA, "Kern", NA, "Lewis")
Test2 = c("A1", "EI1", "B1", "FJ1", "C1", "GK1", "D1", "HL1")

dft2 <- data.frame(ID2, Name21, Name21_1, Name21_2, Test2)
```

For now, I separated columns into two data frames and merged them to get the target data frame. I believe there must be a better way to do this. Appreciate your time. Thank you.